# react-router-redux; redux store and history not syncing correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm attempting to set up routing using react-router-redux with Immutable.js reducers.

I've set up the store using `syncHistoryWithStore`, and when I click on a `Link`, I can see that the correct `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` action is dispatched, that the store is correctly updated with the location information to the routing key of the base reducer, and that the URL is changing to the correct location.

**But** the child components of the new path don't render. The previous path's components are still rendered on the screen. They aren't re-rendered either, they just stay. When I look at the props that are passed to the parent component, the `location` prop still shows the previous route. It's as if the redux action was fired and nothing happened. No new props were passed down.

Here's my *app.js*

```
import configureStore from './config.redux/store';

// import selector for 'syncHistoryWithStore'
import { makeSelectLocationState } from './config.redux/selectors';
// root app
import App from './App';

import { createRoutes} from 'config.routes/routes';

// create redux store with history
const initialState = {};
const store = configureStore(initialState, browserHistory);
// sync history and store, as the react-router-redux reducer
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
    selectLocationState: makeSelectLocationState(),
});
history.listen(location => {
    console.log(location);
});
const rootRoute = createRoutes(store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <Router
                history={history}
                routes={rootRoute}
                render={
                    // Scroll to top when going to new page, imitating default browser behavior
                    applyRouterMiddleware(useScroll())
                }
            />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

*store.js*

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
 const logger = createLogger();

 export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {
    // Create store with middleware
    const middlewares = [
        sagaMiddleware,
        logger,
        routerMiddleware(history) 
    ];

    const enhancers = [
        applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
    ];

    // If Redux DevTools Extension is installed use it, otherwise use Redux compose
    /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
    const composeEnhancers =
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
        typeof window === 'object' &&
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
          window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : compose;
    /* eslint-enable */

    const store = createStore(
        createReducer(),
        fromJS(initialState),
        composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
    );

    // Extensions
    store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
    store.asyncReducers = {}; // async reducer registry
    // Make reducers hot reloadable, see http://mxs.is/googmo
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
            require('./reducers').then((reducerModule) => {
                const createReducers = reducerModule.default;
                const nextReducers = createReducers(store.asyncReducers);

                store.replaceReducer(nextReducers);
            });
        });
    }

    return store;
}
```

*reducers.js*

```
 // initial routing state
  const routeInitialState = fromJS({
      locationBeforeTransition: null,
  });

  // merge route into the global application state
  function routeReducer(state = routeInitialState, action) {
      switch(action.type) {
        case LOCATION_CHANGE:
            return state.merge({
                locationBeforeTransition: action.payload,
            });
        default:
            return state;
      }
  }

  /**
   * Create the main reducer with async loaded ones
   * 
   */
  export default function createReducer(asyncReducers) {
      return combineReducers({
          routing: routeReducer,
          auth: globalReducer,
          ...asyncReducers
      });
  }
```

Any ideas? I've been trying to fix this for a couple days now.